# Amazon Connectで日本の電話番号を取得したい

Tags: aws, amazon

Amazon Connectで日本の電話番号を取得したいのですが、国/地域の選択肢に日本(Japan)がありません。
何か設定が必要なのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なぜか、以下の２つの記事では日本の電話番号の取得ができています。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/amazon-connect-0120/

https://qiita.com/kooohei/items/fec4e677cdfc3d2b35aa#1-%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

AWS東京リージョンではなく、オレゴンリージョンでインスタンスを作成したのが原因のようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、AWSに問い合わせたところ、「東京03」のプレフィックス番号の取得もできるそうです。

お世話になっております。AWSカスタマーサービスの本池でございます。
この度は上限緩和のご申請をいただきまして、誠にありがとうございます。

---

制限緩和のリクエスト 1
サービス: Amazon Connect
リージョン: アジアパシフィック（東京）
制限の名前: 日本 (東京) の電話番号

### 申請する上限数: 1

この度上記の内容でご申請いただいておりましたが、「東京03」のプレフィックス番号を取得されたいということでお間違いございませんでしょうか。
（万一認識に相違がある場合は、お手数ですがご返信にてお知らせくださいませ。）

03のプレフィックス番号を取得するためには、ご住所を証明する書類とインスタンスIDが必要となります。
ご提出いただく書類につきましては、下記のページをご参照ください（個人でのご利用、法人でのご利用により、提出書類が異なっております）。
※法人代表者とは、 CEO や組織長である必要はなく、Connectにて03番号をご利用いただく組織から代表してAWSにご連絡いただく方を指します。

●「03 プレフィックス番号の住所証明に関する要件」

### https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-tokyo-region.html

Amazon Connect インスタンスに使用するために東京の 03 プレフィックス番号の取得リクエストを送信する場合は、
次のように、日本の規制に従って、住所証明に関する次の書類を提出する必要があります。

・Amazon Connect インスタンスを作成するために使用される AWS アカウントが個人向けのものである場合は、
　電話番号が付与されている都市と一致する住所が文書に記載されている、
　政府発行の有効な身分証明書 (個人識別カード、パスポート、運転免許証など) を提出する必要があります。

・企業用の AWS アカウントを使用してインスタンスを作成した場合、その組織の代表者は以下の両方を提出する必要があります。

-政府発行の有効な身分証明書 (個人識別カード、パスポート、運転免許証など)。

-書類に表示され、番号が付与されている都市と一致する住所を含む書類
　 (例: 公益法人、法務省からの企業登録証明書、国または地方の税務申告書、社会保障支払の領収書などの政府機関への支払い済み領収書など)。

### これらの文書のコピーを番号のサポートリクエストとあわせて提出するか、AWS サポートからのリクエスト時に提出します。

また、合わせて該当のConnect Instance ID をお知らせください。

---

### Connect Instance ID：

書類およびインスタンスIDの情報をご提示いただき次第、担当部署にて確認の上、リクエストに対する結果を本ケースよりご連絡差し上げます。